# Tensile strength of a braided steel wire vs. a solid steel bar?

Tags: forces, material-science

I am wondering which one is the strongest between a steel rope and a steel bar with same diameter and made of the same steel?

**EDIT :** The test could be: attach rope/bar to ceiling and suspend a mass until it break

**EDIT2 :** Can I have also some order of magnitude? For example, is the rope 2 times stronger than the bar?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you define 'strongest' to mean exactly. Could you tell something more about the exact test you're thinking of?

Comment: Twist the rope so its load is distributed among all its fibers re sewing thread. Kevlar gives you the same tensile strength for ~20% the mass. Spectra UHMWPE/Plasma is stronger by weight than Kevlar. Both are excellent ropes. Kevlar is certified for elevator cables, Spectra is too soft (re abrasion) there.

Comment: Not the same diameter, but the same area. It is the area (and hence the stress) that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the total cross section of the wires in the rope is equal to the cross section of the steel bar. Since there is some space between the fibers, the rope will have a larger diameter.

If the fibers in the rope were all straight and you were careful to pull equally on each fiber, the bar and rope should be equally strong. But they typically won't be.

Suppose one fiber is a little weaker than the others, and breaks first. Now the rest have a heavier load.

---

In practice, you can buy copper wire in single strand or multiple strand forms.

The advantage of multiple strands is flexibility. You use them in cables you plug in often. Flexing them too much can break individual fibers, and eventually break the wire.

The advantage of single strand is durability. Wires inside walls are single strand because they are inconvenient to replace. They are seldom handled, so stiffness isn't a problem.

Comment: If the wires are inside walls, there are not being moved, so stranded wire will not break from flexing. The stranded wire will be as durable as a single wire if it is running in a wall.

Comment: @LDC3 but it will be stretched, bent, pulled etc during installation - leaving unseen damage

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for steel and aluminum which I have had engineering experience with. The answer is that a solid rod is going to be stronger than a stranded one *of the same area*. There are a few effects to consider, and most of them work against the stranded cables.

1. *Geometry Effects*. Strands are not straight and so pulling on them causes contact pressure between the layers of strands which add to the normal stress. Also the helix angle $\alpha$ causes the internal tensile force to be equal to the external force divided by $\cos \alpha$. The internal normal stress is then $\sigma_N = \frac{F}{A \cos \alpha} > \frac{F}{A } $. For this reason ASTM B221 standard provides for a derating of cables based on the number of layers. Typical values are at about $88\% \ldots 92\%$ for outer layers, and $94\% \ldots 98\%$ for core strands.
2. *Skin Effects*. Stranded cables almost always use heat treated materials, which cause the skin of the strand to be stronger than the core. So overall the smaller the diameter of a strand the higher the ultimate stress. The exception would be soft materials like Aluminum 1350-O or similar. This skin effect is specified as a function of strand diameter $d$ in inches:

   - Aluminum,  $d<0.14$ : $sf=1.213-2.185d$
   - Aluminum,  $d \ge 0.14$ : $sf=0.972-0.402d$
   - Steel, $d={\rm all}$ : $sf = 1.1277-1.096d$
   - Alumoweld, $d={\rm all}$ : $sf = 1.377-2.936d$
3. *Fatigue*. The strands are flexible (which is why they are used) but the internal contacts might cause fretting failures due to small repeating motions between the strands. This is why the fatigue life of a stranded cable is much harder to predict than a solid rod, and typically much less in value.

There is more to this, but I cannot come up with anything right now. Please use comments to add to this list.

Comment: How about oxidation?

Answer (score 1):

My career was as a metallurgist.  The high strength of steel wire is primarily due to cold work, not heat treatment.  Cold drawing of wire, like cold rolling of sheet, plate or rod, basically compresses the material at and near the surface, significantly increasing its strength, especially in the direction of drawing. 
read about the atomic level details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_hardening

Because of all the work hardened surfaces, I believe a steel cable is stronger than a rod of similar size.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know what is the definition of *strength* posed by the question.  For example, can the material be allowed to stretch before it breaks?  Is *strength* the limit before it stretches?  Even if it does not break, can it be allowed to deform gradually?

Consider the case of a steel rope of a crane carrying a heavy load.  It would be much safer to allow such a rope to stretch before it breaks.  In a stretch, the rope is allowed to deform gradually without dropping the entire load. Strength in this case might be the point before it stretches or might be the point where the rope breaks.

An important measure of *strength* is whether this is a measure of maximum **elastic** deformation (such as the *yield point* or the *proportional limit*, a.k.a. the *elastic limit*) beyond which the material will not return to its original shape, or **plastic** deformation (ultimate tensile strength, or UTS), when the material breaks.  A multi-strand rope can introduce additional factors, as noted above.

A stress-strain diagram [typical of carbon steels](https://material-properties.org/what-is-ultimate-tensile-strength-uts-definition/) shows that the yield point can be far less than the UTS.
Since the OP asked about *steel*, we won't go into how *stainless steel*, aluminum, or other metal alloys are different other than to say composition, crystal structure, heat treatment, processing, and history all play [fundamental roles](https://www.me.gatech.edu/me-6796-structure-property-relationships-materials) in determining the mechanical behavior.